# Crash when invoking stringWithString on NSMutableString object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablestring

I have the following code running when the user clicks the "Save" button:

```
- (IBAction) onSaveChangesClick:(id)sender  {

NSMutableString *newGroups = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];


for (int i = 0; i < [self.isInGroupArr count]; i++) {
    if ([[self.isInGroupArr objectAtIndex:i] boolValue] == YES) {
        [newGroups appendString:[[AppDelegate arrayGroups] objectAtIndex:i]];
        [newGroups appendString:@","];
    }
}

//  remove last : ","
if ([newGroups length] > 0)
    newGroups = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[newGroups substringToIndex:[newGroups length] - 1]];


self.contact.groups = newGroups;
[newGroups release];
//[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

`self.IsInGroups` is `BOOL` array and `arrayGroups` is `(NSString *) array` that holds groups names.
I would like to add the `newGroups` string to the `arrayGroups[i]` only `if (IsInGroups[i] == YES)`.

This piece of code generates `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. WHY?

Thanks.

Comment: Where it crashes and what's in your log/console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you create autoreleased instance of NSMutable string.

```
newGroups = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[newGroups substringToIndex:[newGroups length] - 1]];
```

so you shouldn't release it, and all will be fine.

Here is improved code:

```
- (IBAction) onSaveChangesClick:(id)sender  {

NSMutableString *newGroups = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];


for (int i = 0; i < [self.isInGroupArr count]; i++) {
    if ([[self.isInGroupArr objectAtIndex:i] boolValue] == YES) {
        [newGroups appendString:[[AppDelegate arrayGroups] objectAtIndex:i]];
        [newGroups appendString:@","];
    }
}

//  remove last : ","
if ([newGroups length] > 0)
    newGroups = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[newGroups substringToIndex:[newGroups length] - 1]];


self.contact.groups = newGroups;

//[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Explanation:

1. Here you allocate memory and retain it.

   [[NSMutableString alloc] init]
2. [NSMutableString stringWithString:  returns autoreleased instance of NSMutable string, that we shouldn't release(it does the same as [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease] + smth more). and you assign it to variable newGroups(so your old value that was stored in this variable lost)

if ([newGroups length] > 0)
    newGroups = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[newGroups substringToIndex:[newGroups length] - 1]];

1. newGroups here is autoreleased, you release it, and it destroys. But as it was autoreleased, autorelease pool tries to release it again and gets exception(because memory is allready free)

   [newGroups release];

Comment: +1. What u've suggested works perfectly, but I'm trying to avoid autorelease, and more important, to understand the memory management issue here.

Comment: Hi. i've added explanation, hope it will help you

Comment: You were very clear even before the explanation. Thanks! Just 1 more thing - for future similar cases - how can I tell when method returns autorelease object? should I suspect by the name of the function? every stringWithXXX returns autorelease? how can I verify this? google the method name each time?? and BTW - if I do: NSString *str = @"123"; , then str is auto released,right?

Answer (score 2):

```
newGroups = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[newGroups substringToIndex:[newGroups length] - 1]];
```

This line generates a leak, then is the cause of the crash.

After this executes, you no longer have a reference on your alloc/inited mutable string, and you have an autoreleased string. So calling release on that string causes a double release somewhere.

EDIT: with solution

Simplest solution: do not add the last ','.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.isInGroupArr count]; i++) {
    if ([[self.isInGroupArr objectAtIndex:i] boolValue] == YES) {
        [newGroups appendString:[[AppDelegate arrayGroups] objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (i != ([self.isInGroupArr count] - 1))
            [newGroups appendString:@","];
    }
}
```

Not very elegant, but quite efficient (could avoid taking the count each time though).

Comment: OK, got it. How can I release the previous alloc/inited mutable string and override with the new one without using autorelease?

Comment: I'm interested in the memory management concept here, rather than just "getting the job done". U were right about the specific line generated the exception. Do u know how can I get over this exception by releasing the object somehow, or is it not possible? maybe using another helper object?

Comment: if ([newGroups length] > 0)
{
 NSString *temp = [newGroups substringToIndex:[newGroups length] - 1]];
 [newGroups release];
 newGroups = [newGroups mutableCopy];
}

Comment: +1 for the explanations. Tnx. I've Chose to use the autorelease solution though.

Comment: The autorelease is the proper way most of the time, so right choice :)

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated a string(NSMutableString *newGroups = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
)

and then assigning it with an autorelease string(newGroups = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[newGroups substringToIndex:[newGroups length] - 1]];
).

Which you should never do. See this blog - http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/947927280/difficult-bug-finally-solved

Comment out [newGroups release]; and code should work fine.

Also always set NSZombieEnabled environment variable and run the code again, have a look at the crash log, you will get exactly which object is causing the crash.

Comment: OK, but what about the first line: NSMutableString *newGroups = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; ? If I'll omit the last release, I will have the object allocated by this line floating around without been releases. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, you can do it like this, if(newGroups!=nil){newGroups=nil;} and then go ahead and use it. and if you are sure that your newGroups is always going to get assigned to some autorelease String, then alloc it at all. You can also go for AutoRelease pools.

Comment: `if(newGroups!=nil){newGroups=nil;}` doesn't free any memory in iOS, it wouldn't help with the leak.